# Fuzzy matching between two lists - improving double loop for efficiency

Tags: r, parallel-processing, string-matching, lapply, mclapply

I am looking for some advice on the best reworked implementation of the objective of the below MWE that effectively has to check each element in a list against each element in another list using agrep; this example is 2x2 but my actual problem is something like 2,500x75,000 -- so any tips on parallelizing might be also useful.

```
text<-c("The quack brown fox jumps over a lazy dog.", "Pack my box with five dozzen liquor jugs.")
texts<-data.frame(text, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

words<-c("quick","dozen")
search<-data.frame(words, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

texts$match<-""
for (i in 1:nrow(search)) {
  print(i)
  for (j in 1:nrow(texts)) {
    print(j)
    temp<- agrep(search$words[i], texts$text[j], max.distance = 0.1, costs = NULL,
                  ignore.case = TRUE, value = TRUE, fixed = TRUE,
                  useBytes = FALSE)
    #   print(temp)
    if (!((length(temp) == 0) && (typeof(temp) == "character"))) {
      texts$match[j]<-paste0(texts$match[j], search$words[i],';')
    }
    rm(temp)
  }
}
texts
                                        text  match
1 The quack brown fox jumps over a lazy dog. quick;
2  Pack my box with five dozzen liquor jugs. dozen;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could at least drop the second loop, using a vector in the second argument of agrep.

```
text<-c("The quack brown fox jumps over a lazy dog.", "Pack my box with five dozzen liquor jugs.")
texts<-data.frame(text, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

words<-c("quick","dozen")
search<-data.frame(words, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

texts$matchs <- ""
for (i in 1:nrow(search)) { # i <- 1
  print(i)
    temp<- agrepl(search$words[i], texts$text, max.distance = 0.1, costs = NULL,
                 ignore.case = TRUE, fixed = TRUE,
                 useBytes = FALSE)
    #   print(temp)
    if (max(temp) == 1 ) {
      texts$matchs[temp] <- paste(texts$matchs[temp], search$words[i], sep = ';')
    }

}
```